# Отправка сообщений в Telegram

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли подобный метод как в WhatsApp
[https://wa.me/?text=текст](https://wa.me/?text=%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82)
но только для телеграмма, без использования ботов и так далее, чтобы просто перейти по ссылке и выбрать контакт которому отправить сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то искал похожее, но в результате понял, что такого для телеграмма просто не существует. Как Вы правильно подметили, можно создать бота. К сожалению, даже написав бота, У Вас на будет такой возможности, максимум - написать определённом человеку через API.